# Add empty row to WPF DataGrid and edit cells afterwards

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and trying to convert a program from WinForms to WPF. I've come across a hiccup trying to convert from DataGridView to DataGrid and adding rows. Any help is appreciated.

Original code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noteArray.Count; i++)
        {
            int newIndex = dtgrdNotes.Rows.Add();
            dtgrdNotes.Rows[newIndex].Cells[0].Value = noteArray[i].ToString();
            dtgrdNotes.Rows[newIndex].Cells[1].Value = chkbx1.Checked;
            dtgrdNotes.Rows[newIndex].Cells[2].Value = chkbx2.Checked;
        }
```

I need that code to work in WPF and I've tried different variations of **dtgrdNotes.Items** and even a **DataRowView** but nothing has worked so far. any suggestions?

Update* XAML that goes with the controls issue for Richard:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgrdNotes" Height="178" Width="739" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="1" IsEnabled="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtxtbxNote" Width="*" Binding="{Binding note}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgchbxInquire" Width="100" Binding="{Binding inquire}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgchbxPrint" Width="100" Binding="{Binding print}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgbtncDelete" Width="80" Header="Button">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="dgbtncDeleteButton" Content="Delete" Width="50px" Height="10px" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, data controls must be bound to a collection of data, usually are observable collections.
You can try creating a collection with one or more empty you link data and control. The Datagrid, must be equal to the model you are using.
I'll leave you an example:

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgPersons" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="2.5*" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Action">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<Person> Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Id = i;
        p.Age = i + 10;
        p.Name = "Name " + i;
        p.LastName = "LastName " + i;
        p.Status = true;

        Persons.Add(p);
    }

    dtgPersons.ItemsSource = Persons;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var person = dtgPersons.SelectedItem as Person;
    MessageBox.Show(person.Name + " will be removed");
}
```

And the Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, in that example, I can add a new row whenever I want just by creating a new "Person" and then adding that person to the Observable collection?

Comment: Yes it is. one advantage is that if you edit the view, the collection sees the changes automatically

Comment: I'm not sure if I should make a new question for this but maybe you'll know. I'm trying to implement something similar to your example but with the content in the columns being controls (CheckBox, Button, etc.) Every time I try, all i get to appear in the cell is "System.WIndows.Controls.CheckBox" or "System.WIndows.Controls.Button" instead of the actual Control. I've changed the class variable types correctly and, right before it adds the colelction as the DataGrid ItemsSource, it does show correctly as part of my class. The Column is set correctly in XAML for the Checkbox also. Any ideas?

Comment: What you have to do is change the type of column or set a Template for each column according to your needs. Give me a chance and within minutes I update the response code to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my post with what my Xaml currently looks like

Comment: I tried moving this to a chat but I'm too new and it won't let me haha. Everything works at the moment except the button. It doesn't even create the column. And if i set the DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns = false, it just adds a row with no columns or data.

Comment: I actually got it to work now. The way the code handed it, I needed to add the column to the DataGrid with a specific button click.